# Best way to update Interaction.Behaviors

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shader, hlsl

I'm currently using `Interaction.Behaviors` in my app in order to use `BackgroundEffectBehavior`. I'm trying to figure our the best way to update this on a regular basis in XAML or C#. I've already tried c# and C# is turning out to be a dud because of how the shaders are set up.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little broad, could you elaborate some more?

Have you done any research on Blend Behaviors?

I have provided some resources below, but in a nutshell, by using Microsoft Expression Blend (free) you can get the same effects in a drag and drop flavor.

I would highly recommend your view be loosely coupled with your code-behind (MVVM pattern) if you're considering updating your behaviors on a routine(?) basis.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195718(v=vs.110).aspx

https://www.wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html